# Is it possible to change the frequency in which spring actuator performs a health pulse?

Tags: spring, spring-boot-actuator

I am attempting to look around to see how I can modify my actuator end points (specifically health) to limit its frequency. I want to see if I can set it up to being set to trigger once a minute for a specific dataset (ex mail) but leave it for others?

So far I can't seem to find that logic anywhere. The only known way I can think of is creating your own health server:

```
@Component
@RefreshScope
public class HealthCheckService implements HealthIndicator, Closeable {
@Override
public Health health() {
    // check if things are stale
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - this.lastUpdate.get() > this.serviceProperties.getMonitorFailedThreshold()) {
        String errMsg = '[' + this.serviceName + "] health status has not been updated in over ["
                + this.serviceProperties.getMonitorFailedThreshold() + "] milliseconds.  Last updated: ["
                + this.lastUpdate.get() + ']';
        log.error(errMsg);
        return Health.down().withDetail(this.serviceName, errMsg).build();
    }

    // trace level since this could be called a lot.

    if (this.detailMsg != null) {
        Health.status(this.status);
    }

    Health.Builder health = Health.status(this.status); 

    return health.build();
}

/**
 * Scheduled, low latency health check.
 */
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${health.update-delay:60000}")
public void healthUpdate() {
    if (this.isRunning.get()) {
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("Updating Health Status of [" + this.serviceName + "].  Last Status = ["
                    + this.status.getCode() + ']');
        }

        // do some sort of checking and update the value appropriately.
        this.status = Status.UP;
        this.lastUpdate.set(System.currentTimeMillis());

        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("Health Status of [" + this.serviceName + "] updated to [" + this.status.getCode() + ']');
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure if there is a way to set this specifically in spring as a configuration or is the only way around this is to build a custom HealthIndicator?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59151983/7968673